# Splitting string not working with a CSV-style file

Tags: vb.net, csv

I have a textfile with data  like this:

[image]

I want to separate every word into an array, like this:
In Line 1:
"" 
"" 
""
"This PC"
"VGA"
1.000
7.000

Initially, I used .Split(" "), but it will separate "This PC" word. How do I solve this problem?

```
Sub Main()
    Try

        Using sr As New StreamReader("ReadFile.txt")
            Dim line As String

            Do
                line = sr.ReadLine()
                If Not (line Is Nothing) Then



                    Dim wordArr As String() = line.Split(" ")


                    For Each item As String In wordArr
                        'Debug.Write(item & " ")
                        'Show result every item
                    Next

                End If
            Loop Until line Is Nothing
        End Using
    Catch e As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:")
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: check out the TextFieldParser this should allow you to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example bit of code using the textfield parser to do what you're wanting.

```
    Using tfp As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("C:\Users\Charlie\Documents\Test.txt")
        'set the field type to delimited
        tfp.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        'set the delimiter to a space
        tfp.Delimiters = New String() {" "}
        'create a string array to hold the fields
        Dim currentRow As String()

        While Not tfp.EndOfData
            'call ReadFields to fill the string array
            currentRow = tfp.ReadFields()
            'here we're just looping through the row to show the individual fields
            For Each field As String In currentRow
                MsgBox(field)
            Next
        End While
    End Using
```

The result using your example data will show:

an empty string
an empty string
an empty string
This PC
VGA
1.000
7.000

These can also be retrieved just like any array. For example if you wanted to retrieve "This PC" you would use currentRow(3).

Comment: Incidentally, there is also the [TextFieldParser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.hasfieldsenclosedinquotes(v=vs.110).aspx) to be aware of, just in case it doesn't behave as intended.